# Which one is recommended: store css file as binary data or content of css file as text format?

Tags: html, css, postgresql

I am trying to store custom CSS for each user in the database so inside  tag, based on the user I will import particular styling. There are 2 options:

1. store the content of CSS as text format and add it into  tag
2. store CSS as a binary file then decode and use it (haven't figured it out how yet).

The size of CSS is not more than a couple of kilobytes.

I am not sure which option is optimal and recommended in terms of scalability. If it is the second one, how can I import the decoded CSS file inside  tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bytea` and `text` are identical in the way they are stored and the limits. The difference is that `text` is checked for encoding, while `bytea` isn't.

Since CSS are strings, I would use `text` as the more natural data type.

Comment: CSS represents Unicode characters but the [document encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@charset) can be any character encoding. One _could_ choose ASCII.

Comment: Ok, I'll remove the "ASCII" from my answer.